# What's the best way of exploring links between tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm

I'm relatively new to Microsoft SQL Server and have been asked to explore a database based on CRM 2011. I'm slightly overwhelmed by the number of tables and columns within tables and wondered if there was a query that would allow me summarise the metadata of each table.

It might be a newbie question, but I'm stumped.

Comment: query wist you can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA route (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), or you can create some limited digrams (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to SQL Server Management Studio?

If so, expand the database in question, then `Database Diagrams`. If there are any diagrams for your database that will greatly help you visualize the schema. If there are none, you can create new diagrams with a subset of tables (or all tables).

If you can't use SSMS, then here is a link to a list of third-party diagram tools: https://dbmstools.com/categories/database-diagram-tools/sqlserver?commercial=Free